# Scrollviewer logical scrolling with physical scrolling animation (touch)

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a scrollviewer that contains an stackpanel. The stackpanel is filled with usercontrols that I created. I want to use the logical scrolling but with the physical scrolling way of panning to left and right. So when I pan the content to left or right and let go, the content should align to the most visible controls begin position. I am simulating the touch by using input simulator of Microsoft Surface. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement IScrollInfo interface for any custom scrolling.The following link should be helpful

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo